# Unable to resize logo using parameter value

Tags: hugo

I'm running a Hugo website using [Tella Theme](https://github.com/opera7133/tella). I would to enlarge the logo.

`config.toml` has a parameter for sizing:

```
[params.logo]
main = "img/logo/bnb_logo_transparent.svg"
alt = "Logo"
size = "h-14"
```

`h-14` appears too small size. I've tried modifying the `size` to enlarge the logo size but the logo disappears with any other value besides `h-14`. What can I do to resize the logo appropriately?

See attached images.

[image]

[image]

I also began trying to use `custom.css` but I'm not sure if I'm applying it correctly or how Hugo reads a custom css file. There are also two custom.css files available - one under `css folder` and one under `static folder`.

Comment: You should probably ask the maker of the theme.. This isn't a hugo question per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found your website here: https://www.bikenorthbergen.org

The problem is that you have to much whitespace around your logo. I have updated it (I opened the SVG in Inkscape and made the document fit the image). You can find the new logo here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   version="1.1"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 523.5517 246.81982"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg84"
   sodipodi:docname="bnb_logo_transparent.svg"
   width="523.5517"
   height="246.81982"
   inkscape:version="1.2.2 (1:1.2.2+202212051550+b0a8486541)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs
   id="defs88" /><sodipodi:namedview
   id="namedview86"
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1.0"
   inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
   inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
   inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="1.1689453"
   inkscape:cx="128.3208"
   inkscape:cy="122.3325"
   inkscape:window-width="3440"
   inkscape:window-height="1391"
   inkscape:window-x="0"
   inkscape:window-y="0"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1"
   inkscape:current-layer="svg84" />
 <g
   fill="#004d40"
   id="g32"
   transform="translate(-248.31403,-261.80909)">  <path
   d="m 526.05713,294.41211 c 5.77441,2.31006 8.79492,6.84033 8.79492,13.41455 0,11.45996 -6.30762,16.70117 -19.98828,16.70117 h -26.47363 c -4.44141,0 -7.10693,-2.66504 -7.10693,-7.10693 v -45.30664 c 0,-4.44189 2.66553,-7.10693 7.10693,-7.10693 h 24.69678 c 13.68066,0 19.98828,5.24121 19.98828,16.6123 0,5.77441 -2.39844,10.12744 -7.01807,12.61475 z m -13.50342,-5.41895 c 4.7085,0 7.1958,-1.86572 7.1958,-5.86328 0,-3.99756 -2.4873,-6.04102 -7.1958,-6.04102 h -18.03369 v 11.9043 z m 1.42139,23.45312 c 4.79736,0 7.28467,-2.04346 7.28467,-6.12988 0,-3.99756 -2.4873,-5.95215 -7.28467,-5.95215 h -19.45508 v 12.08203 z"
   id="path2" />  <path
   d="m 540.89307,268.82715 c 0,-4.17529 2.75391,-6.84033 6.84033,-6.84033 4.17578,0 6.92969,2.66504 6.92969,6.84033 0,4.17529 -2.75391,7.01807 -6.92969,7.01807 -4.08643,0 -6.84033,-2.84277 -6.84033,-7.01807 z m 12.97021,18.92236 v 30.82617 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04053,-2.48779 -6.04053,-6.48535 v -30.82617 c 0,-3.99756 2.30957,-6.39648 6.04053,-6.39648 3.82031,0 6.12988,2.39893 6.12988,6.39648 z"
   id="path4" />  <path
   d="m 601.74609,314.22266 c 1.15479,1.33252 1.86523,2.75391 1.86523,4.79736 0,3.64209 -2.39844,6.04102 -6.04102,6.04102 -2.04297,0 -3.73096,-0.88867 -5.06348,-2.57666 l -11.72656,-14.56885 -5.50781,4.26416 v 6.396 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04053,-2.48779 -6.04053,-6.48535 v -50.28125 c 0,-3.99805 2.30957,-6.48535 6.04053,-6.48535 3.82031,0 6.12988,2.4873 6.12988,6.48535 v 30.38184 l 17.50098,-15.36865 c 1.33252,-1.24365 2.75391,-1.95459 4.53076,-1.95459 3.46436,0 5.86328,2.31006 5.86328,5.86328 0,2.04346 -0.62207,3.46484 -2.31006,4.79736 l -11.19336,8.88379 12.08203,13.3252 z"
   id="path6" />  <path
   d="m 630.70752,325.59375 c -14.125,0 -23.5415,-9.06104 -23.5415,-22.38672 0,-13.32568 9.4165,-22.38672 23.09766,-22.38672 12.25928,0 21.76465,8.88379 21.76465,19.09961 v 0.71094 c 0,3.81982 -2.4873,6.30713 -6.21826,6.30713 h -26.20703 c 1.33252,5.06396 5.33008,8.17334 11.10449,8.17334 3.82031,0 6.57422,-1.15527 9.23926,-3.64258 1.06592,-1.06592 2.4873,-1.68799 3.99756,-1.68799 3.19824,0 5.33008,2.04346 5.33008,5.2417 0,1.33252 -0.44385,2.4873 -1.24365,3.55322 -3.90869,4.53076 -9.86084,7.01807 -17.32324,7.01807 z M 619.60303,298.5874 h 20.87646 c -0.97705,-4.44189 -5.15234,-7.28467 -10.21582,-7.28467 -5.2417,0 -9.68359,2.84277 -10.66064,7.28467 z"
   id="path8" />  <path
   d="m 536.54004,341.74951 v 45.57324 c 0,4.88623 -2.93164,8.08447 -7.28467,8.08447 -3.02051,0 -5.77441,-1.15527 -7.90674,-3.90918 l -26.91748,-35.35693 h -0.17773 v 32.33643 c 0,4.35303 -2.39844,6.92969 -6.48486,6.92969 -3.99756,0 -6.48535,-2.57666 -6.48535,-6.92969 v -45.57275 c 0,-4.88623 3.19824,-8.08447 7.4624,-8.08447 3.37598,0 5.59668,1.06641 7.55127,3.55371 l 27.09521,35.62354 h 0.17773 v -32.24805 c 0,-4.35303 2.4873,-6.9292 6.48486,-6.9292 4.08643,0 6.48535,2.57617 6.48535,6.9292 z"
   id="path10" />  <path
   d="m 567.72168,351.1665 c 13.76953,0 23.18604,9.06104 23.18604,22.38672 0,13.23682 -9.4165,22.38672 -23.18604,22.38672 -13.68115,0 -23.09766,-9.1499 -23.09766,-22.38672 0,-13.32568 9.4165,-22.38672 23.09766,-22.38672 z m 0,33.66895 c 6.396,0 10.74902,-4.61963 10.74902,-11.28223 0,-6.75146 -4.35303,-11.28223 -10.74902,-11.28223 -6.30762,0 -10.66064,4.53076 -10.66064,11.28223 0,6.6626 4.35303,11.28223 10.66064,11.28223 z"
   id="path12" />  <path
   d="m 628.84033,357.47363 c 0,3.73145 -2.4873,6.04102 -6.04053,6.04102 -7.729,0 -12.08203,3.46484 -12.08203,12.70361 v 12.70361 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04053,-2.48779 -6.04053,-6.48535 V 358.0957 c 0,-3.99756 2.30957,-6.39648 6.04053,-6.39648 3.73145,0 6.04102,2.31006 6.12988,6.04102 h 0.17773 c 2.4873,-4.17529 6.48535,-6.30713 11.9043,-6.30713 3.55322,0 6.04053,2.2207 6.04053,6.04053 z"
   id="path14" />  <path
   d="m 664.81836,388.47754 c -2.66504,4.9751 -7.81738,7.4624 -14.83594,7.4624 -10.57129,0 -16.79004,-6.48486 -16.79004,-17.58936 v -34.55762 c 0,-3.99756 2.31006,-6.48535 6.04102,-6.48535 3.81982,0 6.12988,2.48779 6.12988,6.48535 v 8.43945 h 12.43701 c 3.64209,0 5.95215,2.04346 5.95215,5.50781 0,3.55371 -2.31006,5.59668 -5.95215,5.59668 h -12.43701 v 15.45752 c 0,3.82031 1.9541,6.04102 5.24121,6.04102 2.04346,0 3.37598,-0.88818 4.88623,-2.75391 1.15479,-1.51025 2.75391,-2.2207 4.53027,-2.2207 3.19824,0 5.5083,2.30957 5.5083,5.68555 0,1.06592 -0.2666,2.04297 -0.71094,2.93115 z"
   id="path16" />  <path
   d="m 714.03418,370.88818 v 18.03369 c 0,3.99756 -2.31006,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73145,0 -6.04102,-2.48779 -6.04102,-6.48535 v -16.6123 c 0,-6.57422 -3.02051,-10.03857 -8.88379,-10.03857 -6.12939,0 -9.68311,4.17529 -9.68311,11.19336 v 15.45752 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12939,6.48535 -3.73145,0 -6.04102,-2.48779 -6.04102,-6.48535 v -50.28125 c 0,-3.99805 2.30957,-6.48535 6.04102,-6.48535 3.81982,0 6.12939,2.4873 6.12939,6.48535 v 17.67822 h 0.17773 c 2.84277,-3.28711 7.10693,-5.15234 12.70361,-5.15234 11.6377,0 17.85645,6.9292 17.85645,19.72168 z"
   id="path18" />  <path
   d="m 526.05713,435.104 c 5.77441,2.31006 8.79492,6.84033 8.79492,13.41455 0,11.45996 -6.30762,16.70117 -19.98828,16.70117 h -26.47363 c -4.44141,0 -7.10693,-2.66504 -7.10693,-7.10693 v -45.30664 c 0,-4.44189 2.66553,-7.10693 7.10693,-7.10693 h 24.69678 c 13.68066,0 19.98828,5.24121 19.98828,16.6123 0,5.77441 -2.39844,10.12744 -7.01807,12.61475 z m -13.50342,-5.41895 c 4.7085,0 7.1958,-1.86572 7.1958,-5.86328 0,-3.99756 -2.4873,-6.04102 -7.1958,-6.04102 h -18.03369 v 11.9043 z m 1.42139,23.45264 c 4.79736,0 7.28467,-2.04297 7.28467,-6.12939 0,-3.99756 -2.4873,-5.95215 -7.28467,-5.95215 h -19.45508 v 12.08154 z"
   id="path20" />  <path
   d="m 563.8125,466.28564 c -14.125,0 -23.5415,-9.06104 -23.5415,-22.38672 0,-13.32568 9.4165,-22.38672 23.09766,-22.38672 12.25928,0 21.76465,8.8833 21.76465,19.09961 v 0.71094 c 0,3.81982 -2.4873,6.30713 -6.21826,6.30713 h -26.20703 c 1.33252,5.06396 5.33008,8.17334 11.10449,8.17334 3.82031,0 6.57422,-1.15527 9.23926,-3.64258 1.06592,-1.06592 2.4873,-1.68799 3.99756,-1.68799 3.19824,0 5.33008,2.04346 5.33008,5.2417 0,1.33252 -0.44385,2.4873 -1.24365,3.55322 -3.90869,4.53076 -9.86084,7.01807 -17.32324,7.01807 z m -11.10449,-27.00635 h 20.87646 c -0.97705,-4.44189 -5.15234,-7.28467 -10.21582,-7.28467 -5.2417,0 -9.68359,2.84277 -10.66064,7.28467 z"
   id="path22" />  <path
   d="m 622.35498,427.81934 c 0,3.73145 -2.4873,6.04102 -6.04053,6.04102 -7.729,0 -12.08203,3.46484 -12.08203,12.70361 v 12.70361 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04053,-2.48779 -6.04053,-6.48535 v -30.82617 c 0,-3.99756 2.30957,-6.39648 6.04053,-6.39648 3.73145,0 6.04102,2.31006 6.12988,6.04102 h 0.17773 c 2.4873,-4.17529 6.48535,-6.30713 11.9043,-6.30713 3.55322,0 6.04053,2.2207 6.04053,6.04053 z"
   id="path24" />  <path
   d="m 669.52734,428.44141 v 32.9585 c 0,13.3252 -8.79492,21.40967 -23.00879,21.40967 -8.88379,0 -15.99072,-2.57666 -18.92236,-6.57422 -0.79932,-0.97705 -1.24365,-2.2207 -1.24365,-3.64209 0,-3.46484 2.2207,-5.68555 5.77441,-5.68555 1.42139,0 2.39844,0.44385 3.28711,1.15479 3.10889,2.4873 6.04053,3.73096 10.74902,3.73096 6.9292,0 11.19336,-3.90869 11.19336,-9.77197 v -3.02051 h -0.17773 c -3.10938,3.28711 -7.63965,5.33057 -13.41406,5.33057 -12.1709,0 -20.25488,-8.43945 -20.25488,-21.40967 0,-12.97022 8.08398,-21.40967 20.25488,-21.40967 5.77441,0 10.39355,2.13184 13.50293,5.41895 h 0.17773 c 0.44434,-2.93164 2.66504,-4.88623 5.95215,-4.88623 3.81982,0 6.12988,2.39893 6.12988,6.39648 z m -12.1709,14.48047 c 0,-6.30762 -4.35303,-10.30518 -11.10449,-10.30518 -6.21875,0 -10.30518,3.99756 -10.30518,10.30518 0,6.30713 4.08643,10.30469 10.30518,10.30469 6.75146,0 11.10449,-3.99756 11.10449,-10.30469 z"
   id="path26" />  <path
   d="m 700.70801,466.28564 c -14.125,0 -23.5415,-9.06104 -23.5415,-22.38672 0,-13.32568 9.4165,-22.38672 23.09766,-22.38672 12.25928,0 21.76465,8.8833 21.76465,19.09961 v 0.71094 c 0,3.81982 -2.4873,6.30713 -6.21826,6.30713 h -26.20703 c 1.33252,5.06396 5.33008,8.17334 11.10449,8.17334 3.82031,0 6.57422,-1.15527 9.23926,-3.64258 1.06592,-1.06592 2.4873,-1.68799 3.99756,-1.68799 3.19824,0 5.33008,2.04346 5.33008,5.2417 0,1.33252 -0.44385,2.4873 -1.24365,3.55322 -3.90869,4.53076 -9.86084,7.01807 -17.32324,7.01807 z m -11.10449,-27.00635 h 20.87646 c -0.97705,-4.44189 -5.15234,-7.28467 -10.21582,-7.28467 -5.2417,0 -9.68359,2.84277 -10.66064,7.28467 z"
   id="path28" />  <path
   d="m 771.86572,441.23389 v 18.03369 c 0,3.99756 -2.31006,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04102,-2.48779 -6.04102,-6.48535 v -16.6123 c 0,-6.57422 -3.02051,-10.03857 -8.88379,-10.03857 -6.12939,0 -9.68311,4.17529 -9.68311,11.19336 v 15.45752 c 0,3.99756 -2.30957,6.48535 -6.12988,6.48535 -3.73096,0 -6.04053,-2.48779 -6.04053,-6.48535 v -30.7373 c 0,-3.99756 2.30957,-6.48535 6.04053,-6.48535 3.19824,0 5.41943,1.77686 6.04102,4.79736 h 0.17773 c 2.93164,-3.46484 7.1958,-5.33008 12.79248,-5.33008 11.6377,0 17.85645,6.9292 17.85645,19.72168 z"
   id="path30" /> </g> <g
   fill="#43a047"
   id="g46"
   transform="translate(-248.31403,-261.80909)">  <path
   d="m 269.13625,300.84481 c 3.66744,2.0803 8.33659,2.09651 12.10993,-0.36812 5.38042,-3.51435 6.89313,-10.72517 3.37878,-16.10543 -3.51451,-5.38059 -10.72517,-6.89329 -16.1056,-3.37878 -5.10701,3.3358 -6.72058,9.99882 -3.86707,15.26881 -2.68843,-0.42715 -8.56817,-0.65094 -9.56518,5.29756 -0.78944,4.71002 -2.96055,8.08604 -5.76201,10.0525 -1.73245,1.21594 -1.12691,3.87404 0.96717,4.18103 10.55992,1.54855 18.92408,-5.09371 18.84397,-14.94755 z"
   id="path34" />  <path
   d="m 271.05698,321.78449 c -3.01098,-4.60948 -9.18846,-5.90553 -13.79794,-2.89471 -4.60948,3.01082 -5.90536,9.1883 -2.89454,13.79794 3.01082,4.60931 9.1883,5.90536 13.79778,2.89454 4.60948,-3.01082 5.90536,-9.1883 2.89471,-13.79778 z"
   id="path36" />  <path
   d="m 280.27252,340.11698 c -2.31317,-3.54143 -7.05952,-4.53715 -10.60095,-2.22398 -2.11792,1.38346 -3.31683,3.63792 -3.45046,5.98353 l 19.12679,4.01075 -5.07539,-7.7703 z"
   id="path38" />  <path
   d="m 357.54011,318.52458 c 0.94755,0.77257 2.28609,0.84311 3.30953,0.17449 l 15.83478,-10.34294 c 1.10258,-0.72019 1.55649,-2.10965 1.09188,-3.34164 l -6.69269,-17.74674 c -0.63343,-1.68007 -2.6594,-2.34187 -4.1627,-1.35994 l -24.20542,15.81045 c -1.5912,1.03934 -1.71169,3.32624 -0.23855,4.52726 l 15.06318,12.27907 z"
   id="path40" />  <path
   d="m 449.9406,319.15606 h -1.2534 c 0.91317,-3.43311 1.45952,-7.66149 1.45952,-12.25361 0,-11.43077 -3.34391,-20.69707 -7.46899,-20.69707 -4.12508,0 -7.46883,9.2663 -7.46883,20.69707 0,6.62864 1.12869,12.51454 2.878,16.30263 l -12.29464,16.16917 v -6.79713 c 4.08243,-1.92607 7.19347,-11.75024 7.19347,-23.61173 0,-13.243 -3.87404,-23.97855 -8.65315,-23.97855 -4.77911,0 -8.65315,10.73555 -8.65315,23.97855 0,11.86165 3.1112,21.68597 7.19363,23.61173 v 10.6363 l -8.91489,11.72429 v -5.23642 c 2.47015,-1.8098 4.2939,-8.02734 4.2939,-15.44135 0,-8.83088 -2.58351,-15.98965 -5.77028,-15.98965 -3.18677,0 -5.77012,7.15876 -5.77012,15.98965 0,7.41418 1.82358,13.63172 4.2939,15.44135 v 9.11954 l -7.70041,10.12709 c -5.63633,7.41272 -14.41337,11.765 -23.72541,11.765 h -8.61568 c -6.97827,0 -13.43468,3.69517 -16.96931,9.71211 l -15.67244,26.67849 c -1.78645,3.04131 -5.04993,4.909 -8.57709,4.909 h -8.92316 c -1.67179,0 -3.31667,0.42131 -4.78251,1.22518 l -14.93344,8.18788 c -0.60505,0.33163 -1.24286,0.59954 -1.90321,0.79917 l -21.9422,6.63496 v -0.50256 c 2.47031,-1.80964 4.2939,-8.02718 4.2939,-15.44135 0,-8.83088 -2.58334,-15.98965 -5.77012,-15.98965 -2.32452,0 -4.32276,3.81728 -5.23674,9.30571 -0.78846,-2.29858 -1.89575,-3.74852 -3.1305,-3.74852 -2.3902,0 -4.32795,5.36923 -4.32795,11.99268 0,5.55589 1.37049,10.18483 3.22067,11.54688 v 7.24828 c -0.27488,0.25833 -0.54699,0.5204 -0.79236,0.81036 l -3.34975,3.95886 c -5.47043,6.46517 -0.87506,16.37317 7.59386,16.37317 h 180.17887 c 5.49394,0 9.94774,-4.45379 9.94774,-9.94774 V 329.10379 c 0,-5.49394 -4.45379,-9.94774 -9.94774,-9.94774 z m -181.41621,122.5481 v -5.68108 c 0.97674,-0.71922 1.81629,-2.33652 2.3928,-4.54412 0.76835,3.34651 1.97164,5.83823 3.39094,6.87821 v 1.39546 l -4.07594,1.23248 c -0.59613,0.18033 -1.16048,0.4338 -1.7078,0.71905 z"
   id="path42" />  <path
   d="m 277.38025,382.49549 6.63042,-4.33087 c -4.82451,8.51709 -4.86797,19.36729 0.8436,28.11174 8.1454,12.47027 24.91669,15.98916 37.38647,7.84425 12.46929,-8.14475 15.98721,-24.91621 7.84198,-37.38647 -5.82006,-8.91018 -16.04284,-13.21884 -25.95522,-11.99868 l -0.16395,-0.68127 5.12404,-3.34699 3.71593,-2.42718 20.77848,14.08222 c 2.35063,1.59395 5.24064,1.9817 7.92777,1.06382 0.72797,-0.24844 1.40908,-0.58137 2.03311,-0.9889 0.12795,-0.0835 0.23612,-0.19087 0.3592,-0.28055 2.10154,1.03415 4.55045,1.33384 6.92102,0.66213 l 7.4998,-2.1236 c 0.63051,-0.17871 1.2114,-0.44596 1.73245,-0.78635 0.73203,-0.47823 1.33108,-1.10875 1.79991,-1.82196 8.7691,6.07726 20.70891,6.63172 30.17728,0.4471 12.46978,-8.14491 15.9877,-24.91653 7.8423,-37.3868 -8.14459,-12.46913 -24.91588,-15.98802 -37.38566,-7.84311 -1.73342,1.13226 -3.27483,2.44485 -4.65505,3.87566 L 335.53467,310.0328 c 1.46941,-2.163 1.50995,-5.09258 -0.14449,-7.30374 -2.08581,-2.78654 -6.03704,-3.34813 -8.82083,-1.26848 l -11.88062,8.89186 -29.23232,-5.95547 c -2.24457,-0.45667 -4.56147,0.34218 -6.04986,2.08257 -1.48838,1.74282 -1.9131,4.15573 -1.10939,6.30154 l 12.13442,32.41374 c 1.06253,2.83795 3.99388,4.51753 6.97941,3.99956 l 1.58147,-0.27455 8.40081,5.69357 -1.60239,1.04664 -6.90302,4.50893 -3.04504,-4.66169 c -0.54148,-0.82917 -1.39043,-1.40924 -2.35971,-1.61244 l -36.65088,-7.68532 c -3.25553,-0.68257 -5.71141,2.91141 -3.89237,5.69617 l 19.27258,29.50574 c 1.12756,1.72628 3.44138,2.21182 5.16782,1.0841 z m 35.48343,-31.45516 -5.31929,-3.60517 14.15714,-2.06019 c 2.09732,-0.30536 4.17665,0.65905 5.29837,2.45734 l 2.26679,3.63387 c -2.41696,1.91699 -5.26853,3.56933 -8.72093,4.74586 l 0.0154,0.0449 -2.28722,-1.55001 -5.41026,-3.66663 z m 24.10001,16.33328 -9.89665,-6.70729 c 2.11062,-1.03301 4.03524,-2.20354 5.75147,-3.50608 l 6.60674,10.59122 c -0.84133,0.24406 -1.73034,0.11692 -2.46155,-0.37785 z m 22.01096,-31.71431 16.44858,12.64768 c 1.04274,0.80257 2.44291,0.81603 3.48549,0.13509 0.2765,-0.18066 0.52786,-0.40996 0.74079,-0.68678 1.01453,-1.31973 0.76754,-3.21126 -0.55186,-4.2253 l -16.45588,-12.65352 c 0.95014,-0.9229 1.99435,-1.77428 3.14412,-2.52529 9.68713,-6.32749 22.71574,-3.59479 29.04291,6.09202 6.32797,9.68778 3.5943,22.71607 -6.09299,29.04372 -9.68729,6.32749 -22.71591,3.59463 -29.04372,-6.09315 -4.41358,-6.75707 -4.40628,-15.13405 -0.71743,-21.73446 z m -9.32014,24.3924 1.92202,-5.85882 c 0.52056,1.61795 1.19745,3.20234 2.04284,4.73645 z m -49.25202,-24.16764 -6.3137,-16.86649 20.85454,4.24784 c 1.76196,0.36001 3.60549,-0.0509 5.03338,-1.12967 l 10.84972,-8.12042 11.16108,8.76991 c -0.023,2.0031 -0.29125,7.54229 -2.41323,13.71069 l 4.15719,7.0026 c 2.782,-5.8259 3.98172,-11.65083 4.50163,-15.80591 l 4.13805,3.25148 -6.85324,22.38168 -7.80144,-13.14132 c -3.47089,-5.84471 -10.30224,-8.99029 -16.99882,-7.82738 l -20.31516,3.527 z m -4.40839,38.05364 c 1.1848,-0.77387 2.42085,-1.40795 3.68722,-1.91456 l 4.85776,20.18738 c 0.38872,1.61731 2.01656,2.61464 3.63501,2.22511 0.34526,-0.0832 0.66181,-0.22331 0.94301,-0.40704 1.03674,-0.67722 1.58763,-1.95591 1.28146,-3.2291 l -4.85467,-20.177 c 7.48748,-0.6777 15.10275,2.68681 19.49265,9.40755 6.32797,9.68778 3.5943,22.71623 -6.09251,29.04339 -9.68729,6.32749 -22.71574,3.59479 -29.04356,-6.09299 -6.32733,-9.68681 -3.59365,-22.7151 6.09364,-29.04275 z"
   id="path44" /> </g> <g
   fill="#43a047"
   id="g82"
   transform="translate(-248.31403,-261.80909)">  <path
   d="m 269.32373,496.37256 c 6.76611,0.0425 9.14941,1.87256 9.14941,5.95801 0,3.91504 -3.36182,6.29834 -8.93701,6.29834 -4.12793,0 -7.10693,-0.93652 -9.10693,-2.89404 -0.29785,-0.29785 -0.42578,-0.68066 -0.42578,-1.06396 0,-0.85107 0.59619,-1.4043 1.31934,-1.4043 0.55322,0 0.89355,0.25537 1.23438,0.55322 1.53174,1.36182 3.95752,2.12793 6.80908,2.12793 3.83008,0 6.17041,-1.4043 6.17041,-3.65967 0,-2.08545 -1.53174,-2.93652 -6.3833,-3.02148 -6.59619,-0.12793 -8.85205,-1.74512 -8.85205,-5.5752 0,-3.83008 3.48975,-6.34082 8.85205,-6.34082 3.44727,0 6.00049,0.76611 7.87305,2.38281 0.34033,0.29834 0.51074,0.63867 0.51074,1.19189 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.4043 -1.31934,1.4043 -0.42578,0 -0.80859,-0.17041 -1.10645,-0.42578 -1.44727,-1.19141 -3.61719,-1.91504 -5.7876,-1.91504 -3.74512,0 -6.04346,1.40479 -6.04346,3.70264 0,1.87256 1.44727,2.63867 6.04346,2.68115 z"
   id="path48" />  <path
   d="m 302.90039,489.18018 v 17.61865 c 0,0.979 -0.51074,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93604,0 -1.48926,-0.5957 -1.48926,-1.57471 v -2 h -0.0855 c -1.61719,2.42578 -4.46826,3.83008 -8.12842,3.83008 -6.12793,0 -10.25586,-4.25586 -10.25586,-10.63916 0,-6.38379 4.12793,-10.63916 10.25586,-10.63916 3.66016,0 6.51123,1.4043 8.12842,3.83008 h 0.0855 v -2.00049 c 0,-1.021 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48926,-1.57422 0.93604,0 1.44678,0.55322 1.44678,1.57422 z m -2.93604,8.80957 c 0,-4.72412 -3.19189,-8.00098 -7.74561,-8.00098 -4.59619,0 -7.74512,3.23438 -7.74512,8.00098 0,4.76611 3.14893,8.00049 7.74512,8.00049 4.55371,0 7.74561,-3.23438 7.74561,-8.00049 z"
   id="path50" />  <path
   d="m 311.36963,485.69092 v 2.17041 h 8.85156 c 0.89404,0 1.44727,0.46777 1.44727,1.31885 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.31934 -1.44727,1.31934 h -8.85156 v 16.29932 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -21.06543 c 0,-4.93652 2.85156,-7.91553 7.5752,-7.91553 3.14941,0 5.57471,1.36182 6.7666,3.65967 0.12744,0.25537 0.21289,0.51074 0.21289,0.76611 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.36182 -1.36182,1.36182 -0.55322,0 -1.02148,-0.38281 -1.27686,-0.85107 -0.80859,-1.48975 -2.29834,-2.29834 -4.21338,-2.29834 -3.02148,0 -4.76611,1.87256 -4.76611,5.23486 z"
   id="path52" />  <path
   d="m 341.75586,499.01123 h -16.25684 c 0.46826,4.17041 3.48975,6.979 7.95801,6.979 2.72363,0 4.93652,-1.06396 6.25586,-2.76611 0.25537,-0.34033 0.68066,-0.5957 1.19141,-0.5957 0.80859,0 1.36182,0.55322 1.36182,1.36182 0,0.34033 -0.085,0.5957 -0.29785,0.89355 -1.82959,2.34082 -4.89404,3.74512 -8.51123,3.74512 -6.59619,0 -10.97949,-4.29834 -10.97949,-10.63916 0,-6.34082 4.3833,-10.63916 10.72412,-10.63916 6.04297,0 10.42627,4.21289 10.42627,9.87305 0,1.14893 -0.68066,1.7876 -1.87207,1.7876 z m -16.17188,-2.55371 h 15.27783 c -0.5957,-3.87256 -3.53223,-6.46875 -7.66016,-6.46875 -4.08545,0 -7.02197,2.59619 -7.61768,6.46875 z"
   id="path54" />  <path
   d="m 365.80078,496.37256 c 6.76611,0.0425 9.14941,1.87256 9.14941,5.95801 0,3.91504 -3.36182,6.29834 -8.93701,6.29834 -4.12793,0 -7.10693,-0.93652 -9.10693,-2.89404 -0.29785,-0.29785 -0.42578,-0.68066 -0.42578,-1.06396 0,-0.85107 0.5957,-1.4043 1.31934,-1.4043 0.55322,0 0.89355,0.25537 1.23438,0.55322 1.53174,1.36182 3.95752,2.12793 6.80908,2.12793 3.83008,0 6.17041,-1.4043 6.17041,-3.65967 0,-2.08545 -1.53174,-2.93652 -6.3833,-3.02148 -6.59619,-0.12793 -8.85205,-1.74512 -8.85205,-5.5752 0,-3.83008 3.48975,-6.34082 8.85205,-6.34082 3.44727,0 6.00049,0.76611 7.87305,2.38281 0.34033,0.29834 0.51074,0.63867 0.51074,1.19189 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.4043 -1.31934,1.4043 -0.42578,0 -0.80859,-0.17041 -1.10645,-0.42578 -1.44727,-1.19141 -3.61768,-1.91504 -5.7876,-1.91504 -3.74512,0 -6.04346,1.40479 -6.04346,3.70264 0,1.87256 1.44727,2.63867 6.04346,2.68115 z"
   id="path56" />  <path
   d="m 392.65332,504.96875 c -1.19141,2.34082 -3.53223,3.66016 -6.72363,3.66016 -4.59619,0 -7.44775,-2.979 -7.44775,-7.91553 V 482.5415 c 0,-0.979 0.55322,-1.57471 1.44727,-1.57471 0.93604,0 1.48926,0.5957 1.48926,1.57471 v 5.31982 h 8.85205 c 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.46777 1.44678,1.31885 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.31934 -1.44678,1.31934 h -8.85205 v 10.25635 c 0,3.36182 1.74463,5.23438 4.68115,5.23438 2.04297,0 3.40479,-0.89355 4.21338,-2.46826 0.2124,-0.42529 0.63818,-0.72363 1.19141,-0.72363 0.76611,0 1.31934,0.59619 1.31934,1.40479 0,0.29785 -0.085,0.5957 -0.17041,0.76562 z"
   id="path58" />  <path
   d="m 408.10205,488.88232 c 0,0.93652 -0.5957,1.44727 -1.44727,1.44727 -4.80859,0 -7.48975,2.93604 -7.48975,8.89404 v 7.5752 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -17.61865 c 0,-1.021 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48975,-1.57422 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.55322 1.44678,1.57422 v 2.29834 h 0.085 c 1.4043,-2.59619 3.91553,-4.00049 7.40479,-4.00049 0.85156,0 1.44727,0.46826 1.44727,1.4043 z"
   id="path60" />  <path
   d="M 428.23145,499.01123 H 411.9751 c 0.46826,4.17041 3.48975,6.979 7.95801,6.979 2.72363,0 4.93652,-1.06396 6.25586,-2.76611 0.25537,-0.34033 0.68115,-0.5957 1.19141,-0.5957 0.80859,0 1.36182,0.55322 1.36182,1.36182 0,0.34033 -0.085,0.5957 -0.29785,0.89355 -1.82959,2.34082 -4.89404,3.74512 -8.51123,3.74512 -6.59619,0 -10.97949,-4.29834 -10.97949,-10.63916 0,-6.34082 4.3833,-10.63916 10.72412,-10.63916 6.04297,0 10.42627,4.21289 10.42627,9.87305 0,1.14893 -0.68066,1.7876 -1.87256,1.7876 z m -16.17139,-2.55371 h 15.27783 c -0.5957,-3.87256 -3.53223,-6.46875 -7.66016,-6.46875 -4.08545,0 -7.02197,2.59619 -7.61768,6.46875 z"
   id="path62" />  <path
   d="m 452.61719,499.01123 h -16.25684 c 0.46826,4.17041 3.48975,6.979 7.95801,6.979 2.72363,0 4.93652,-1.06396 6.25586,-2.76611 0.25537,-0.34033 0.68066,-0.5957 1.19141,-0.5957 0.80859,0 1.36182,0.55322 1.36182,1.36182 0,0.34033 -0.085,0.5957 -0.29785,0.89355 -1.82959,2.34082 -4.89404,3.74512 -8.51123,3.74512 -6.59619,0 -10.97949,-4.29834 -10.97949,-10.63916 0,-6.34082 4.3833,-10.63916 10.72412,-10.63916 6.04297,0 10.42627,4.21289 10.42627,9.87305 0,1.14893 -0.68066,1.7876 -1.87207,1.7876 z m -16.17188,-2.55371 h 15.27783 c -0.5957,-3.87256 -3.53223,-6.46875 -7.66016,-6.46875 -4.08545,0 -7.02197,2.59619 -7.61768,6.46875 z"
   id="path64" />  <path
   d="m 472.3208,504.96875 c -1.19141,2.34082 -3.53223,3.66016 -6.72363,3.66016 -4.59619,0 -7.44775,-2.979 -7.44775,-7.91553 V 482.5415 c 0,-0.979 0.55322,-1.57471 1.44727,-1.57471 0.93604,0 1.48926,0.5957 1.48926,1.57471 v 5.31982 h 8.85205 c 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.46777 1.44678,1.31885 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.31934 -1.44678,1.31934 h -8.85205 v 10.25635 c 0,3.36182 1.74463,5.23438 4.68115,5.23438 2.04297,0 3.40479,-0.89355 4.21338,-2.46826 0.21289,-0.42529 0.63818,-0.72363 1.19141,-0.72363 0.76611,0 1.31934,0.59619 1.31934,1.40479 0,0.29785 -0.085,0.5957 -0.17041,0.76562 z"
   id="path66" />  <path
   d="m 484.02441,496.37256 c 6.76611,0.0425 9.14941,1.87256 9.14941,5.95801 0,3.91504 -3.36182,6.29834 -8.93701,6.29834 -4.12793,0 -7.10693,-0.93652 -9.10693,-2.89404 -0.29785,-0.29785 -0.42578,-0.68066 -0.42578,-1.06396 0,-0.85107 0.5957,-1.4043 1.31934,-1.4043 0.55322,0 0.89355,0.25537 1.23438,0.55322 1.53174,1.36182 3.95752,2.12793 6.80908,2.12793 3.83008,0 6.17041,-1.4043 6.17041,-3.65967 0,-2.08545 -1.53174,-2.93652 -6.3833,-3.02148 -6.59619,-0.12793 -8.85205,-1.74512 -8.85205,-5.5752 0,-3.83008 3.48975,-6.34082 8.85205,-6.34082 3.44727,0 6.00049,0.76611 7.87305,2.38281 0.34033,0.29834 0.51074,0.63867 0.51074,1.19189 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.4043 -1.31934,1.4043 -0.42578,0 -0.80859,-0.17041 -1.10645,-0.42578 -1.44727,-1.19141 -3.61768,-1.91504 -5.7876,-1.91504 -3.74512,0 -6.04346,1.40479 -6.04346,3.70264 0,1.87256 1.44727,2.63867 6.04346,2.68115 z"
   id="path68" />  <path
   d="m 510.15332,485.69092 v 2.17041 h 8.85156 c 0.89404,0 1.44727,0.46777 1.44727,1.31885 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.31934 -1.44727,1.31934 h -8.85156 v 16.29932 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -21.06543 c 0,-4.93652 2.85156,-7.91553 7.5752,-7.91553 3.14941,0 5.57471,1.36182 6.7666,3.65967 0.12744,0.25537 0.21289,0.51074 0.21289,0.76611 0,0.80859 -0.55322,1.36182 -1.36182,1.36182 -0.55322,0 -1.02148,-0.38281 -1.27686,-0.85107 -0.80859,-1.48975 -2.29834,-2.29834 -4.21338,-2.29834 -3.02148,0 -4.76611,1.87256 -4.76611,5.23486 z"
   id="path70" />  <path
   d="m 531.98535,487.35059 c 6.38379,0 10.76709,4.29834 10.76709,10.63916 0,6.29834 -4.3833,10.63916 -10.76709,10.63916 -6.34082,0 -10.72412,-4.34082 -10.72412,-10.63916 0,-6.34082 4.3833,-10.63916 10.72412,-10.63916 z m 0,18.63965 c 4.63867,0 7.78809,-3.23438 7.78809,-8.00049 0,-4.7666 -3.14941,-8.00098 -7.78809,-8.00098 -4.59619,0 -7.74512,3.23438 -7.74512,8.00098 0,4.76611 3.14893,8.00049 7.74512,8.00049 z"
   id="path72" />  <path
   d="m 559.22217,488.88232 c 0,0.93652 -0.5957,1.44727 -1.44727,1.44727 -4.80859,0 -7.48975,2.93604 -7.48975,8.89404 v 7.5752 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -17.61865 c 0,-1.021 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48975,-1.57422 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.55322 1.44678,1.57422 v 2.29834 h 0.085 c 1.4043,-2.59619 3.91553,-4.00049 7.40479,-4.00049 0.85156,0 1.44727,0.46826 1.44727,1.4043 z"
   id="path74" />  <path
   d="m 592.96875,489.18018 v 17.61865 c 0,0.979 -0.51074,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93604,0 -1.48926,-0.5957 -1.48926,-1.57471 v -2 h -0.0854 c -1.61719,2.42578 -4.46826,3.83008 -8.12842,3.83008 -6.12793,0 -10.25586,-4.25586 -10.25586,-10.63916 0,-6.38379 4.12793,-10.63916 10.25586,-10.63916 3.66016,0 6.51123,1.4043 8.12842,3.83008 h 0.0854 v -2.00049 c 0,-1.021 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48926,-1.57422 0.93604,0 1.44678,0.55322 1.44678,1.57422 z m -2.93604,8.80957 c 0,-4.72412 -3.19189,-8.00098 -7.74561,-8.00098 -4.59619,0 -7.74512,3.23438 -7.74512,8.00098 0,4.76611 3.14893,8.00049 7.74512,8.00049 4.55371,0 7.74561,-3.23438 7.74561,-8.00049 z"
   id="path76" />  <path
   d="m 601.43799,479.64746 v 27.15137 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -27.15137 c 0,-0.97852 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48975,-1.57422 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.5957 1.44678,1.57422 z"
   id="path78" />  <path
   d="m 609.90625,479.64746 v 27.15137 c 0,0.979 -0.55322,1.57471 -1.44678,1.57471 -0.93652,0 -1.48975,-0.5957 -1.48975,-1.57471 v -27.15137 c 0,-0.97852 0.55322,-1.57422 1.48975,-1.57422 0.89355,0 1.44678,0.5957 1.44678,1.57422 z"
   id="path80" /> </g>
</svg>
```

To make the logo bigger you can set the h-24 class instead of the h-14.

Comment: Thank you! Very strange as I tried to resize the default logo from the theme and had similar issues. The theme maker also wasn't sure what the problem was when I opened an issue on GH.